# Summing divergent asymptotic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, divergent-series

I found the sine integral si to be

$$Si (x)\sim \frac \pi 2+\sum _{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\frac{(2 n-1)! \sin (x)}{x^{2 n}}+\frac{(2 n-2)! \cos (x)}{x^{2 n-1}}\right)$$

Say I want to find $Si(\frac \pi 4)$ what options have I got to use this divergent series to find the actual value?

Comment: Lol, it depends on the way this is asymptotic... You need more information than just asymptotic to know the error. Asymptotic by itself doesnt mean nothing to evaluate a value (I not downvoted you).

Comment: The asymptotic series uniformly diverge.  Their "usefulness" is that a truncated series will become closer and closer to the function they intend to approximate as the argument becomes larger and larger.  $\pi/4<1$ and the "usefulness" of the asymptotic series here is dubious.

Comment: This series diverges, first of all, $cos(x)$ can be brought outside of the first summation and once you compute the first summation it turns out to diverge. Therefore the entire series diverges.

Comment: 1-2+3-4.. also diverges but we have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%E2%88%92_2_%2B_3_%E2%88%92_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF |||||||||||| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: @grdgfgr but why that, when we have $1+2+3...={{-1} \over 12}$ (^.^)

Comment: Because I am not interested in what would happen if I added the numbers using an abacus. I want to find what the sum represents.

Comment: for values as small as $\pi/4$ maybe the standard taylor expansion would provide a better choice?! Even if one only takes the first term it seems that we are just 4% off---

Comment: in contrast the asymptotic expansion overestimates by a factor of 2

Comment: @tired my goal is not to find Si(pi/4), my goal is to be able to make use of a divergent series.

Comment: it may well be that the asymptotic series explodes before you can grasp enough terms to make a good approximation for values as small as $\pi/4$. I don't see the point here: for small values the taylorexpansion is good in this case, no need for more fancy stuff whioch probably will not work as wished

Comment: You _may_ be able to apply [Borel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation) to this asymptotic series.

Answer (score 3):

In order to find a good approximation of $\text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, I strongly suggest you to use a converging series and not a diverging one. For instance, the almost trivial:
$$\text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n+1}}{4^{2n+1}(2n+1)(2n+1)!}$$
converges pretty fast.

Comment: is there a good rule of thumb for which value of $x$ to switch between asymptotic and converging  expansions. The radius of convergence seems a very rough estimate

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really answer my question. My goal is to explicitly make use of a divergent series.

Comment: @tired the taylor series converges for all reals (as does most taylor series with a factorial in the denominator) while the asymptotic series will diverge for even very large (fixed) values of x (as does most series with a factorial in the numerator). However a truncated asymptotic series will be incomparably better than taylor series for large values (say, larger than 3) of x.

Comment: @tired and asymptotic series will be terrible for small x while that's where taylor series is accurate

Answer (score 2):

For the computation of $\text{Si}(x)$, you can avoid summations and use Pade approximants $[n+1,n]$ and they are very accurate for $0<x<\pi$.

The best formulation write $$\text{Si}(x)=x \frac{P_n}{Q_n}$$

For example, for $n=8$ $$P_8=1-\frac{4094517636881845481 x^2}{104725905364944197604}+\frac{3080478831447814421
   x^4}{3490863512164806586800}-$$ $$\frac{1307662727118635527267
   x^6}{173447044465420580071744800}+\frac{8312356513454527739283241
   x^8}{339990896561117421056634156960000}$$ $$Q_8=1+\frac{191509801858462833 x^2}{11636211707216021956}+\frac{151401002938061331
   x^4}{1163621170721602195600}+$$ $$\frac{142463152299901321
   x^6}{235982373422340925267680}+\frac{109740904565879261
   x^8}{76143645824275338553038080}$$

Applied to $x=\frac \pi 4$, this approximation gives $$\text{Si}(\frac \pi 4)\approx 0.758975881068782699682925759337$$ while the "exact" value is $$\text{Si}(\frac \pi 4)\approx 0.758975881068782699681242985677$$

According to Wikipedia, the  formula obtained fo $n=12$ is accurate to better than $10^{−16}$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ 4$.

While $$s_p=\sum_{n=0}^p\frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n+1}}{4^{2n+1}(2n+1)(2n+1)!}$$ would give $$s_1=0.758482992668021382380004322324$$ $$s_2=0.758981071582059926412007482008$$ $$s_3=0.758975846410033901090466538410$$ $$s_4=0.758975881227999349736261215637$$ $$s_5=0.758975881068249561241406575169$$ $$s_6=0.758975881068784057647090162047$$ $$s_7=0.758975881068782696962863719284$$ $$s_8=0.758975881068782699685631148010$$ $$s_9=0.758975881068782699681237153361$$

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really answer my question. My goal is to explicitly make use of a divergent series.